# Adblock Plus - disabled by default and enable per site

Tags: firefox-extensions, adblock

I have Adblock Plus disabled by default at the moment, and I would like to block ads on some sites. Is this possible with Adblock, or do I need another addon?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am assuming that you are asking about [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/). I cannot answer your question for other extensions, some of them implemented the [Adblock Plus filter syntax](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters) in a slightly broken way.

Yes, running Adblock Plus in a whitelist mode is possible. It is somewhat awkward however, the user interface support for this feature is still very lacking. First of all you need to add the custom filter `@@*$document` that will have the effect of disabling Adblock Plus everywhere.

To add this filter in Firefox:

- Click the Adblock Plus icon.
- Choose "Filter Preferences" from the menu  (you can also press Ctrl+Shift+F).
- Switch to "Custom filters" tab.
- If you don't have any filter group yet, click "Add filter group". Otherwise just select it.
- Click "Add filter" button on the right and enter this filter.

To add this filter in Chrome or Opera:

- Right-click the Adblock Plus icon.
- Choose "Options" from the menu.
- Switch to "Add your own filters" tab.
- Enter the filter into the text field and click "Add filter".

The tricky part is updating the filter whenever you want to allow blocking on a particular website. Currently that's significantly simpler in Firefox:

- When on the website, click the Adblock Plus icon.
- Choose "Open blockable items" from the menu (you can also press Ctrl+Shift+V).
- There will be only one entry, right-click it.
- Choose "Disable this filter on example.com" where example.com is the site you are on.
- Click the cross symbol in the upper-right corner of the blockable items list or press Ctrl+Shift+V again to close blockable items.

This will automatically change the filter you've added into something like `@@*$document,domain=~example.com`.

Now if you are on Chrome or Opera, there is currently no way to do that automatically - you will have to go into Adblock Plus options and edit the filter manually. That's actually easier if you click the "Edit filters as raw text" at the bottom of the "Add your own filters" tab. If you want to allow blocking on multiple domains the filter has too look like this: `@@*$document,domain=~example.com|~example.info|~foo.example.org`.

*Disclaimer*: I am the lead developer of Adblock Plus.

Comment: Nice to hear from you. Even though this solution is not intuitive, it works! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for your detailed explanation. Unfortunately for me it became too cumbersome - I shall wait until the adblock allows a "per site, ad allowed". It is not that I necessarily want to disable all ads per se, but the annoying ones that are useless to me, I never want to see; yet there may be a few per-site ads that are ok for me, but the above method is too cumbersome.

Comment: @wladimir patant, I think it would be a really good idea to implement this in a way that it is intuitive for people to use. I think a lot of people feel guilty blocking ads everywhere, even with the new nice list.

Answer (score 0):

Normal adblock does this. Select customise, then "Show ads everywhere except for these domains...", then type in ebay.com or ~ebay.com|~mesg.ebay.com if you have trouble in the message system.

Comment: I think you are talking about AdBlock extension, not AdBlock Plus.